# django_markdown doesn't work on my template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, markdown

I'm using the module `django markdown` and it doesn't work on my template, but it does on *django admin*

My Django version is **1.8.5** and I'm using the latest version of django markdown

I followed the steps showed in the repository's README [https://github.com/klen/django_markdown](https://github.com/klen/django_markdownhttp://)

setup ( add django_markdown in settings and url are both ok )

in model.py ( migrate is ok )

```
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField
class MyModel(models.Model):
    description = MarkdownField()
```

python manage.py collectstatic is ok

forms.py

```
class BidForm(BaseBidForm, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ('name', 'description')
    description = forms.CharField(widget=MarkdownWidget())
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(models.Bid)
class BidAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):   
    formfield_overrides = {MarkdownField: {'widget': AdminMarkdownWidget}}
```

template .html

```
    {% load django_markdown %}

    {% for field in form %}

        {% if field.html_name == 'description' %}
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ form.description.html_name }}">{% trans "Descripción" %} <span class="red">*</span> <small class="required">(obligatorio)</small></label><br>
            <textarea  id="new" class="form-control {{ field.errors|yesno:'error,' }}" rows="3" 
            name='{{ form.description.html_name }}' 
            placeholder="{% trans "ejemplos" %}" 
            value="{% if form.description.value %}{{ form.description.value }}{% endif %}"></textarea>    
         {% markdown_editor "#new" %}
         {% markdown_media %}
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
```